# Degree of a regular graph to be connected

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Let $G$ be a graph of $\;n\;$ vertices in which every vertex has a degree equal to $\;d\;$.How large must $\;\;d\;\;$ be for $\;G$ to be connected?

Please provide a hint! (I should try at least from my side :) )

Thanks !

Comment: It could be as low as $2$, but I assume you mean "How large must $d$ be to _guarantee_ that $G$ is connected?"

Comment: Exactly the sufficient degree.

Comment: I think you mean how small, because $d=n$ works.

Comment: I can think of a graph which is not connected, the disjoint union of two complete graphs., e.g. $K_5\cup K_5$.  Every one of those ten vertices has degree four, but there are two connected components... I wonder how many connected components are possible if I try to increase the degree a little bit more...

Comment: @JMoravitz So we clearly need $d$ to be larger than $\frac{n}{2}-1$. What about $\frac n2$?

Comment: @Arthur: Have you considered the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: @Arthur The op requested a hint, not a full solution.  I could of course invoke Ore's theorem or Dirac's theorem and be done.

Comment: @Debashish, for a graph to be connected, it should be possible to traverse a vertex from any other vertex. For the degree of n vertices to be connected , d can be as large as 2. Think of a straight line with points on it as vertices. Of course both the end points should be vertices as well.

Comment: @Babu read the very first comment.  We have already pointed out that a cycle is connected and $2$-regular, but not all $2$-regular graphs are connected.  The question is for a given $n$ to find the smallest value of $d$ such that **every** $d$-regular graph is connected (*and further every $k$-regular graph where $k\geq d$*), not just that *some* $d$-regular graph is connected.

Comment: @JMoravitz, ok got it

Comment: @Arthur it appeared the question was directed to me, and I was justifying not answering it.

Comment: @JMoravitz Now that you say it, I see it. To be clear, my question was not directed at you, although there is no way to tell from how I wrote it.

Comment: yes, @AlexR. The minimum sufficient degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Compiling information so the question can be removed from unanswered queue*)

The graph $K_5\cup K_5$, the disjoint union of two complete graphs on five vertices, is an example of a $4$-regular graph on ten vertices which is not connected.

> Generalizing, $K_{n/2}\cup K_{n/2}$ for $n$ even is an example of an $n/2 - 1$ regular graph which is not connected.

If you were to suppose that a graph *wasn't* connected, then there must be at least two connected components, and at least one of those must be the "smallest" or tied for the smallest in terms of number of vertices. (*why?*).  Further, the vertices in that smaller component must have smaller than a certain degree (*why?*).  This all implies something useful.

(*Note: a bit of extra care needs to be taken for the argument for $n$ odd, but you can skirt around the issue by remembering the handshaking lemma implies you cannot have an odd number of odd degree vertices*)

Comment: We have a counter example $K_{n/2}\cup K_{n/2}$ where the total graph is regular($d = 4$) still disconnected.The only way to increase $+1$ degree is to connect $n/2$ vertices pairs and we got d = $n/2$ and the total graph is connected. In case of odd vertices, we have two components of sizes $\left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil \text{ and } \left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil -1$. And the larger complete component is having $d = \left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil -1$ degree at max but still disconnected overall. If $d$ is odd then answer would be $d+1$ otherwise $d+2$. correct?

Comment: your second paragraph is trying to maximize degree (min) up to a sufficient amount in the disconnected state and then $+1$  to connect those two components. is that right?

Comment: @Debashish My second paragraph isn't trying to "connect the components" it is trying to give you an idea on how to construct a proof by contradiction that had there been multiple components and at least a certain degree, at least one of the components would have been too "degree heavy."  If you want to think of it as "I'm connecting the components" then sure... but the point is that who is to say there are any components to connect in the first place.  We are after all trying to properties of *all* graphs with $n$ vertices, not just those with multiple components.